# Not able to get delete event in ng2-smart-table in angular 6

Tags: angular, delete-row, ng2-smart-table

I'm using `ng2-smart-table` to display data in angular 6 app. Now I'm not able to get delete event. I have set setting object like this.

```
columns: {
  ... // Columns... 
},
edit: {
  confirmSave: true,
  editButtonContent: '...',
  saveButtonContent: '...',
  cancelButtonContent: '...'
},  
delete: {
   confirmDelete : true,
   deleteButtonContent: '...',
   saveButtonContent: '...',
   cancelButtonContent: '...'
},
```

In HTML file I have set this.

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="Settings" [source]="DataSource" (createConfirm)="onCreate($event)" (confirmDelete)="onRoleDelete($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

In .ts file

```
onRoleDelete(event) {
   alert("Delete works");
}
```

I have check it's `git` and also refer other examples also. I'm also able to get edit event but not getting only delete event.

Delete icon is also view in `HTML` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `deleteConfirm` instead `confirmDelete`

> Please refer Demo for better understanding

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table)

Remove `mode: 'external',`

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="DataSource" (createConfirm)="onCreate($event)" (deleteConfirm)="onRoleDelete($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
```

Configure:

```
  settings = {
    delete: {
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    add: {
      confirmCreate: true,
    },
    edit: {
      confirmSave: true,
    },
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID',
      },
      name: {
        title: 'Full Name',
      },
      username: {
        title: 'User Name',
      },
      email: {
        title: 'Email',
      },
    },
  };

  data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Leanne Graham",
      username: "Bret",
      email: "Sincere@april.biz"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Ervin Howell",
      username: "Antonette",
      email: "Shanna@melissa.tv"
    },

    // ... list of items

    {
      id: 11,
      name: "Nicholas DuBuque",
      username: "Nicholas.Stanton",
      email: "Rey.Padberg@rosamond.biz"
    }
  ];

  onDeleteConfirm(event) {
    console.log("Delete Event In Console")
    console.log(event);
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }

  onCreateConfirm(event) {
    console.log("Create Event In Console")
    console.log(event);

  }

  onSaveConfirm(event) {
    console.log("Edit Event In Console")
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Reference ---> https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/various/advanced-example-confirm.component.ts

Comment: @UnluckAJ Still not getting event.

Comment: Check spelling of Settings its settings or Settings?

Comment: share complete code HTML and Css if possible or create stackblitz example

Comment: Hello , As per you say I have make a stackblitz project link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohumhy

Comment: For just demo, I have create a test component and put my code it it.

Comment: please refer my demo i have kept every thing in that

Comment: Yes , I have check your link. And it works fine. When I compare our code. I didn't get any mistake. It's look like both are same. I didn't get what am I missing... :(

Comment: let me check it again.

Comment: I got it remove mode: 'external',

Comment: Let me try by remove it

Comment: Hey , It works fine now. Thank you so much for that. You made my day...